# Issue with Raphael JS animate object over custom path

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, svg, raphael

I have looked into http://raphaeljs.com/gear.html this demo code.

But it uses eliipse and by default it's position (x,y) is same as it's center.
When I use image the image flips in a strange unpredictable manner.

What I want to do is animate movement of image from one point to another over a quadratic beziar curve, with rotation of image along the path.

Can anyone please please help me in this ?

Comment: Where's your specific problem? What have you tried?

Comment: My specific problem is like this. Suppose I have two points & I want to animate a custom image like bus on a custom path between these two points. Then how to achieve the same with RaphaelJS. If one draws a circle instead of image then there is no problem, but in case of image, it doesn't turn along with path. Can you please suggest how can I do it ? I want to have turning of image as per curve on the path like in animateAlong method. This is something that I am experimenting on my own.